# While form submitting using ajax..getting Post not supported error ...don't know what is the error?

Tags: ajax, spring, forms, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am using form submission using AJAX in Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. When I try to submit it it shows

> Post method is not supported

I can't figure out the mistake in my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" th:action="@{/teacher/teacherProfileUpdation}" th:object="${teacherProfileDetailsList}"
                         id="saveTeacherForm" method="POST" >
<br />
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-14 col-md-12">
        <br />
        <h5 style="margin-left: 15%;">Personal Details</h5>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <input placeholder="Teacher first name" id="txtTeacherFname" th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <input placeholder="Teacher middle name" id="txtTeacherMname" th:field="*{middleName}" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <input placeholder="Teacher last name" id="txtTeacherLname" th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-14 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnStudentByIdInSchoolAdmin" value="0" /> 
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="btnUpdateTeacherProfile" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
saveTeacherProfile :function(){
    $("#saveTeacherForm").ajaxForm({
        success : function(status) { 
            alert("success");
        },
    }).submit();
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateTeacherProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateTeacherProfile( TeacherProfileDetails teacherProfileDetails){

        System.out.println("-----------"+teacherProfileDetails.getFirstName()+"-------------");
        System.out.println("-----------"+teacherProfileDetails.getLastName()+"-------------");
        System.out.println("-----------"+teacherProfileDetails.getMiddleName()+"-------------");

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: where do see the error message, on the client or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the form, but most likely your Spring controller is not configured to accept POST requests. Try this in your server-side Controller class for this page:

```
@RequestMapping(..., method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, ...)
public void myControllerMethod()
{
```

Comment: so i have to use both "RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST" right?

Comment: not always: Maybe you have one method that serves both a GET and a POST request (GET for the initial call, POST for the form submission call). Then you declare both. But it can be the case, that you have two different methods declared in your controller, one for the GET, one for the POST - then you would configure each method with either RequestMethod.GET or RequestMethod.POST.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping(..., method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, ...) 
public String updateTeacherProfile( TeacherProfileDetails teacherProfileDetails){
//ur Logic
}